# Erlang sample project in erlide (eclipse)

Tags: erlang, erlide

Guys, I just started learning erlang ... and since I'm a java programmer, I'm using eclipse ... I downloaded erlide already ... but now is looking for any tutorial in the net on how to use erlide to create a simple erlang project. Anyone knows where could I get it?
Thanks in advance.

Bromo

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The erlide site has a tutorial: http://erlide.sourceforge.net/erlide.html#create_project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not erlide specific, but good to get used to the OTP project structure and intricacies:

http://20bits.com/articles/erlang-a-generic-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this guide is accurate, but the other stuff in the blog post was good: http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/erlang-getting-started-and-using-eclipse/